# Restore drive image with PC reboot

Tags: command-line, restore, hard-drive-image

I need a way to restore a drive image (C:) automatically.. My client earlier had some **Norton Ghost 2003 floppy disk** with some batch program to initiate a **Drive Restore operation** via the command-line of GHOST.EXE *(the main executable of Norton Ghost 2003)*

Any available programs that can restore a **drive image via the command line**, or similiar? *Preferably via a Shell command.*

Comment: the windows system image and "wbadmin" is probably a better answer today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page)

Comment: How do I get this functioning on a Windows XP machine?!

Comment: There's a bootable CD that boots up Linux, so you can completely bypass windows.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking up SystemRescueCd - http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux live CD at hand, you can use the power of `dd`.

Take image with something like:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip > /path/to/my/image.img.gz
```

And restore it with something like:

```
zcat /path/to/my/image.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda1
```

Comment: ntfsclone is probably easier (and certainly faster) than dd

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to restore from an existing image, if so then you need the tool that made it.

Do you want to set up a system where you can easily restore from an image you've presently made, then ghost should be able to do it, but there are plenty of others.

Do you want to set up a system where each reboot restores the system to a former known good state? If so, then look at [Rollback Rx Pro](http://www.horizondatasys.com/169620.ihtml), and there are other similar systems as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have TWO networked pc's and two linux live cd's you can dump the image across the network using netcat as well;

```
dd if=/dev/sda | nc otherhost portnumber
```

On otherhost you do

```
nc -l portnumber | dd of=/dev/sda1
```

You have to run on otherhost *first*. This saves you the trouble of storing the image anywhere.

Comment: +1 very nice. You could have piped through some compression program too ;)

Comment: Think of the things you could do with THREE pc's and THREE live cd's ;)

Answer (score 1):

A little plug for my favorite [drivesnapshot](http://drivesnapshot.de/) - a little simpler for windows users in that you can back up windows while it's running and restore the OS partition from within windows

If your system can no longer boot there is also a restore cd/USB/Floppy.

Answer (score 0):

[SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) - It's a **livecd** that allows to use **Partimage** immediately even if your computer has **no OS installed** (useful to restore an image), and it allows to save an image on a DVD on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Clonezilla http://clonezilla.org/. It has all you need!

> 'Clonezilla Live' enables a user to
>   clone a single computer's storage
>   media, or a single partition on the
>   media, to a separate medium device.
>   The cloned data can be saved as an
>   image-file or as a duplicated copy of
>   the data. The data can be saved to
>   locally attached storage device, a SSH
>   server, Samba Server or a NFS
>   file-share. The clone file can then be
>   used to restore the original when
>   needed.
>
> The Clonezilla application can be run
>   from a USB-flash-drive, a CD-ROM, or a
>   DVD-ROM. Clonezilla requires no
>   modification to the computer; the
>   software runs in its own booted
>   environment.